# How to use grep/awk/sed to isolate part of a file between delimiters, potentially crossing lines

Tags: bash, awk, grep, sh

I am trying to obtain a specific part of an output file using a bash script, but I don't know how to proceed. First of all, the data I need are between `\HF=` and the first occurrence of another `\.` The values are separated by comma, but sometimes there are line breaks in the middle of them. What I need is to `grep` all these values and send them to a new file containg just them, one per line.

An example of the outputfile I have:

```
...\HF=-56.876868,-56.2343,-42.
343,-67.3453423,-85.74656,-
45.864\...
```

I tried to use `grep -Pzo`, but I have no idea how to use it.

As mentioned, one value can be broken in two lines:

```
...-90.80
234,...
```

And it must be considered the same number. Sometimes just the minus sign is in the upper line and the rest of the number in the next line:

```
...,-
56.656,...
```

An output exemple from [Gaussian](https://gaussian.com/):

```
 433513773\H,-0.5821679865,0.6475216708,0.9536248473\H,-0.7834605038,0.
 4523031701,2.780055657\\Version=ES64L-G09RevD.01\HF=-156.0385049,-156.
 312885,-156.0311709,-156.0310505,-156.0309275,-156.0308023,-156.030548
 ,-156.0304151,-156.0302832,-156.0301504,-156.0300168,-15,8492,84298484
 .0385128\RMSD=4.113e-09,3.064e-09,3.538e-09,3.945e-09,9.452e-09,9.542e
 -09,9.805e-09,9.877e-09,9.916e-09,2.730e-09,3.175e-09,3.077e-09,3.301e
```

**An exemple of what must be the file I need**

```
-156.0385049
-156.312885
-156.0311709
-156.0310505
-156.0309275
-156.0308023
-156.030548
-156.0304151
-156.0302832
-156.0301504
-156.0300168
-156.84928429
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Yes, but the values are beetween \HF= and a single backslash \

Comment: Why would you want to use "grep, awk and sed" when awk alone can do all the work? Do you just mean you want an answer that uses only *standard UNIX tools*? Then say that.

Comment: (That said, `grep -P` and `grep -z` aren't standard at all, so if they're allowed, you might as well use something equally nonstandard like Python).

Comment: Also, is there a reason you don't use, say, `tr -d '\r\n'` to eliminate newlines wholesale?

Comment: (I also reworded the title, since "localize" has a specific meaning that doesn't apply here; it implies that you're not just trying to extract a subset, but to modify it to comply with the local language or locale).

Comment: What is the record delimiter?

Comment: I found that after a line break there, in the next line there is a space befere the rest of the number

Comment: @ozuz ismail, it worked! In my terminal its is 100%, but when I added a >the_file_i_need.out in the end, when I open the text file some spaces appers in the middle of the number

Comment: weird. how does `cat -A the_file_i_need.out`'s output look like? can you post some lines from it?

Comment: -156.0382962$<br>
-156.0383468$<br>
-156.0383908$<br>
-156.038428$<br>
-156.0384585$<br>
-156.0384822$<br>
-156.0384992$<br>
-156.0385094$<br>
-156.0385128$<br>

Comment: can't see any spaces in the middle of numbers

Comment: What I used:
sed -z 's/\n //g' gaussian.log | grep -Po '\\HF=\K[^\\]*' | tr ',' '\n' >the_file_i_need.out

Comment: I so sorry, my fault. I was opening a old version of the output, the names I created were similar to each other. Now its is 100% working. I am grateful for your help

Answer (score 3):

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\' -F, -v OFS='\n' 'sub(/^HF=/,""){gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,""); $1=$1; print}' file
-156.0385049
-156.312885
-156.0311709
-156.0310505
-156.0309275
-156.0308023
-156.030548
-156.0304151
-156.0302832
-156.0301504
-156.0300168
-15
8492
84298484.0385128
```

Looks like the last field in your sample input isn't what you expected it to be. If your awk doesn't support POSIX character classes, e.g. nawk, then just change `[[:space:]]` to `[ \t\n]`.

Comment: @vintnes Assigning anything to a field causes the record to be reconstructed using the value of OFS between the fields. So if you just want to replace all FSs with OFSs then assign a field to itself. Try `echo 'a,b' | awk -F, -v OFS='#' '{print; $1=$1; print NF, $0}'`. So in the code above I'm replacing `,`s with `\n`s across the whole record just like if I'd written `gsub(/,/,"\n")` but without the undesirable re-splitting into fields that would have happened with the latter. Compare previous NF to NF in the output of `echo 'a,b' | awk -F, -v OFS='#' '{print; gsub(/,/,"#"); print NF, $0}'`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
awk -F '\' '!p && $2 ~ /^HF=/ { $1=""; p=$0; next }
    p && NF>1 { p = p $1; print p; p="" }
    p { p = p $0 }' file >newfile
```

If we see `HF=`, start collecting stuff into `p`. If `p` is set, we are collecting; continue collecting until we see another backslash. When we see it, print the collected `p`, and start over with empty `p` (i.e. we are no longer collecting for output until we see the next start marker again).

Notice that this assumes that there is never more than a single backslash on a line. If you need to support that, a slightly more complex script is required. (In particular, you can't trust `$2` to contain `HF= but you'd have to loop through all fields and check which one is the actual start.)

`grep` is not suitable for this, and Bash itself is not particularly well-equipped, either. You could try `sed` but it's more of a write-only language so it's rarely recommended for nontrivial tasks.

Comment: Beetween \HF= and \ there are just the numbers and commas

Comment: The interesting question is if there could be additional backslashes before or after, but on the same line.

Comment: Oh, there maybe have. The output from GAUSSIAN are not well formated

Comment: You don't mention this tool at all in the question, so I thought you put in the tag by mistake. The [tag:gaussian] is about a mathematical concept, not a specific tool, though. Maybe you want to update your question with a link to more information about this specific tool.

Comment: GAUSSIAN is an computational chemistry software. In this case not a gaussian normal distribution

Answer (score 0):

`sed` solution :

```
sed -En '/\HF/{
s/^.*\HF=//;
:label1
N;
/\\/!{b label1}
N;
s/[[:space:]]+//g;
s/,/\n/g;s/\\.*//gp;
q;
}' file > outfile
```

**Output**

```
-156.0385049
-156.312885
-156.0311709
-156.0310505
-156.0309275
-156.0308023
-156.030548
-156.0304151
-156.0302832
-156.0301504
-156.0300168
-15
8492
84298484.0385128
```

<sub>**Regret**: Hardcoded a newline here :(</sub>